# Meteor: Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: Match is not defined

Tags: meteor

I was working on a project using version 0.9.3.1 of Meteor.  I've just upgraded to version 1.2.0.1 in order to resume my project.

I've installed the latest version of meteor-roles by running `meteor add alanning:roles` so that should be up to date.  I've had a look at the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check_package) but that hasn't really helped.

Anyone got any ideas on what this error is and how to resolve it?

```
Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: Match is not defined
    at Object.Roles._uiHelpers.isInRole (http://localhost:3000/packages/alanning_roles.js?0f20b892d4a0a11a6ea8431da3d0a0953ba951a9:809:10)
    at bindDataContext (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:2986:16)
    at Blaze._wrapCatchingExceptions (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:1650:16)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:3038:66
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:3671:12)
    at wrapHelper (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:3037:27)
    at Spacebars.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?1aedcc2aa3ae9ff5d860d73516110cedd77c033e:167:18)
    at Spacebars.mustacheImpl (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?1aedcc2aa3ae9ff5d860d73516110cedd77c033e:104:25)
    at Object.Spacebars.dataMustache (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?1aedcc2aa3ae9ff5d860d73516110cedd77c033e:136:39)
    at http://localhost:3000/app/client/layout/adminlayout.compiled.html.js?c582d42dde65584f4e6c48e70d8d65fa2cba7589:6:22
```

Comment: `meteor add check` ?

Comment: Usually when I see a cryptic error like this I set a breakpoint in the package code (`alanning_roles.js` line 809) and then look to see what it's doing and what it might be expecting. Most often that leads back to an error in my own code but sometimes it leads to finding a bug in the package in which case I report it to the author on gitHub.

Comment: After the upgrade to 1.2 packages should be declaring new dependencies for packages that used to be pre-installed.  In this case, `alanning:roles` needs to declare `check` .  I have submitted a pull request to the repo but it does not seem to be very active.

Comment: Oh no :( ...... might mean rewriting the roles part of my project.  Any other packages you would recommend that do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

challett appears to have fixed this issue:

https://github.com/challett/meteor-roles/commit/dfd967e1e2ea27dc20b34e2bd17f38de70ebed72

```
//roles/package.js

 Package.describe({
   summary: "Authorization package for Meteor",
-  version: "1.2.12",
+  version: "1.2.13",
   git: "https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles.git",
   name: "alanning:roles"
 });
 @@ -8,7 +8,7 @@ Package.describe({
 Package.on_use(function (api) {
   api.versionsFrom && api.versionsFrom("METEOR@0.9.0");
   var both = ['client', 'server'];
-  api.use(['underscore', 'accounts-base'], both);
+  api.use(['underscore', 'accounts-base', 'check'], both);
   api.use(['handlebars'], 'client', {weak: true});
```

Answer (score 8):

I believe that [this open issue](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/issues/130) on GitHub against `alanning:roles` has the clue you are looking for. You may need to install the `check` package as it may be an undeclared dependency.

```
$ meteor add check
```

Comment: Thank you, I did install that but sadly it didn't help :(

Comment: I am on windows 10 and its working like charm Thanks